# Writing a function to split a data set into two

Tags: function, variables, split, arguments, categories

## First, split the max_hf data set into two groups, Y and N.

def split_data_hf(old_data, new_data, variable, category):
    new_data = old_data[old_data.variable == category]

split_data_hf(max_hf, max_hf1, inducted, 'Y')
split_data_hf(max_hf, max_hf2, inducted, 'N')

When I try to run this, I get the error that the variable inducted (which I am trying to pass through) is not defined. Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Theoretically it should work, and if I remove the variable input from the split_data_hf function and then add inducted in place of variable, then it runs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, I think I figured it out myself.

Instead of having

old_data[old_data.variable == category]

One should write:

old_data[old_data[variable] == category]

Then, when the input variable is passed, write "...." to pass the argument through.

Thanks!